# when does the ruby class 'inherited' hook method fire?

Tags: ruby

When does the inherited hook fire?

I'm asking because I need a way to fire it before any code inside the inheriting class is fired.

At the same time I don't want this code to run inside the parent class (which is why I can't just dump the code into the parent class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base class's `self.inherited` method (if defined) is invoked *before* the body of he child class is evaluated.

This is trivially easy to prove to yourself:

```
class Base
  def self.inherited(what)
    puts "base"
  end
end

class Child < Base
  puts "child"
end
```

The output is

> base
>   child

However, I cannot find any guarantee that this is the case. Until you do so, I wouldn't necessarily assume this is true for all currenta nd implementations of Ruby.